# Should I Choose Hosting Location From Traffic Source Location?

Tags: server, traffic, geolocation

I am running my blog site on godaddy shared hosting, at US. But my site's top visitors percentage are as follows:

India - 25%
USA   - 15%
UK    -  4%

Now as major are from india, should I choose a hosting/server located near it, like singapore or so? Will that be of any benefit, such as by improving the loading experience for major visitors?

Is there any other factors that I should consider for server location?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use hosting in your target region, if you value visitors more from India then it would make sense to move your hosting their. Additionally you should try to cater for your audiences in US and UK, you can do this by using a CDN on images so that content is sent from a server near them rather than going all the way from India.

Another important factor is are you sure that 25% of those people in India are actually visitors and not spammers and bots? as I have 1,000 of visits on one of my website that is a PLIGG site and 99% of the visitors are from India using spam tools, or they are looking for vulnerability or comment spam... My site is actually top 30,000 on alexa thanks to these people from India but I'm constantly having to delete the entries as spam.... So check to see if your bounce rate is increasing as a result or page on time, and if any of them are using comments.

Comment: Thanks, I will rethink about it. But I think the % is more or less correct. almost all traffics are from search engine and number of searches/query terms and traffic do seems make sense together. However, learned new thing from you though. Thanks.